# Add external Angular JS $scope.variable to HTML script tag variable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using AngularJS to retrieve some JSON data. Once the data is retrieved it should be accessible from the `index.html` page within `<script>` tags. Currently, I am able to print the `$scope.article_names` variable onto the body of the HTML page however I cannot understand why I am unable to retrieve that same Angular `$scope` variable within Javascript tags.

Here is the Angular code:

```
app.controller('dataCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/article_names")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.article_names = response.data;
    });
    console.log('test')
});
```

And the HTML is:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dataCtrl">
    <div >
        <h1>This is a test</h1>
            {{ collection_find }}
            {{ article_names }}
            <!--The below prints the result output gathered from angular -->
            {$ article_names $}
        <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'javascript/angular.js' %}"></script>
    <script>
        var article_names = $scope.article_names;
        // this does not print anything to the console
        console.log(article_names);
    </script>
```

How can I access that `$scope.article_names` variable into local `<script`  tags? The thing I cannot understand the most is the fact that the `$scope.article_names` is accessible within the main body of the HTML, but does not work within `<script` tags

Comment: Well that's the point of Angular, to use controllers, components and services. Thankfully, Angular's variables are not global but scoped to controllers. Each `$scope` is defined inside its controller, not globally.

Comment: Yes and my <script> tags from where I am trying to access the Angular variable from is inside the controller.

Comment: Uh, no, it's in your HTML template, directly under the `<body>` tag. You're directly trying to access `window.$scope` which is of course undefined.